# Is this the right way to make an iPad app full screen?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to disable the status bar in iOS to make my app full-screen. I managed it but I'm not sure I did it correctly.

Here's what I did:

1. In IB, set the Simulated Metric for Status Bar to None
2. Added an entry in the Info.plist `UIStatusBarHidden = YES`
3. Moved my views around in IB so they fill the screen.

I'm not using OpenGL or anything like that, it's just a straightforward Cocoa Touch app which, like many others of a similar type, benefits from having access to every pixel on the screen.

To my shame I got the technique from one of those omnipresent 'tutorials' that litter the web like the dust bunnies under my bed. It was dated 2009. Is there a more modern, approved technique I should be using instead?

If it helps I'm targeting iOS 5 only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `statusBarHidden` property of the shared `UIApplication` object](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW18) controls whether the status bar is visible.  [The `UIStatusBarHidden` entry in the app's `Info.plist`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW15) sets the value of that `statusBarHidden` property when the application is launched.  You can change the property's value to hide or show the status bar while your app is running.

These are the current methods for controlling the status bar's visibility as of iOS 5.0.1.